# Disable indentation for one paragraph

Tags: indentation, paragraphs

I have written the following :

```
\par{first paragraph}
\par{second paragraph}
\par{third paragraph}
```

Now, I want to disable indentation for the third paragraph.
I naturally add `\noindent` command as following :

```
\par{first paragraph}
\par{second paragraph}
\noindent\par{third paragraph}
```

But it doesn't produce any effect.
Then, I found several ways to achieve that, but I still ask myself why `\noindent` is not working properly.

Thanks for sharing !

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! And with a simple  `\par\noindent Third paragraph? B.t.w.,  the `\par`  command has no argument.

Comment: You got it. `\noindent\par` doesn't work whereas `\par\noindent` works.

Comment: @thoo-ma becase `\par` **ends** a paragraph (as a blank line do; you normally do not use explicit `\par` in a document, unless you have a clear reason to). So you should have `first \par second \par \noindent third \par` (no braces!)

Comment: `\par` takes no argument and it ends a paragraph not start one.

Comment: you should almost never need `\par` or `\noindent` in a document, what is the use case here? certainly if you do use `\par`  place it at the end of the paragraph, not the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I strongly suggest you undo an apparent writing habit that has a worrisome [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) flavor, i.e., that you replace

```
\par{first paragraph}
\par{second paragraph}
\par{third paragraph}
```

with

```
first paragraph

second paragraph

third paragraph
```

Why? Mostly to reduce pointless code clutter, but also to acknowledge that (a) `\par` is a *switch* and does not take an argument and (b) TeX creates paragraph breaks *automatically* whenever it encounters one or more all-blank lines.

Second, to inhibit the paragraph indentation which happens if the parameter `\parindent` takes a positive length, all you need to do is to insert `\noindent` at the *start* of the paragraph, or paragraphs, in question.

Finally, it should be obvious why `\noindent\par{third paragraph}` doesn't produce the desired effect: `\noindent` occurs at the end of the second paragraph and *not* at the start of the third paragraph. Hence, it can have no effect on the indentation of the first line of the third paragraph.